# Java var deduction fails with generics

Tags: java

Considering the following example :

```
import java.lang.System;

interface Copy {
    
}

class Impl implements Copy {
    
    public <T extends Copy> T copy() {
        return (T)new Impl();
    }
    
    public void method() { System.out.println("hello"); }
    
}

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
      var impl = new Impl();
      impl.method();
      var copy = impl.copy(); // deduction fails here
      copy.method();
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make it deduce the type while still using var ?

*Note: If I replace `var copy = impl.copy();` by `Impl copy = impl.copy();` the compiler gets it.*

Running with OpenJDK 11.0.6

Comment: Why do you exepct `copy` to be an `Impl`? The compiler only knows that it has to be a `T extends Copy` without any further constraints. The only thing it knows about it for sure is that it's a `Copy`. Also be aware that the unconstraint `T extends Copy` is actually kind of a lie and the method contains an unchecked cast which breaks the type system. `AnotherClassImplementingCopy x = impl.copy()` would compile but break at runtime.

Comment: My thought was that was `T` would be deduced by the compiler by looking at the return type of the function. But the cas to `T` in the return should have get my attention in the first place !

Comment: Also thanks for the "kind of a lie" thing, generics in java kind of disturbs me.

Comment: The one thing you have to keep in mind is that the generics type system is correct **if and only if** all involved code compiles without warning. So whenever you see a warning like "unchecked cast" (the most common one) you know that there's a chance that you're breaking generics. There are ways to make the method you wrote safe (usually by passing in a `Class<T>`), but they make the method harder to use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `var`, there is no way for the compiler to infer the type of `T` and in Java generics are compile time constructs and with type erasure, all the generic syntax is removed at runtime.
If you just want to use `var`, you can explicitly specify the generic type:

```
var copy = impl.<Impl>copy();
```

You can also simply write:

```
public Copy copy()
{
    return new Impl();
}
```

This introduces the same constraint that `T extends Copy` does.

I'm not sure what you are exactly trying to achieve but usually, an interface is a contract which specifies that any class that implements it must contain all the methods of that interface. Your interface does not contain any methods, its just a marker interface like `Serializable`. If you are trying to enforce that any class that implements `Copy` must contain a `copy` method, then the interface must define the signature of this method:

```
interface Copy {
    public Copy copy(); 
}

class Impl implements Copy {
    
    @Override
    public Impl copy() {
        return new Impl();
    }
    
    public void method() { System.out.println("hello"); }
}

class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      var impl = new Impl();
      impl.method();
      var copy = impl.copy(); 
      copy.method();
 
    }
}
```

Java supports covariant return types and hence you don't even need generics in the first place. You can observe that in `Impl` I've defined the method as `public Impl copy()` and it still works becuase `Impl` implements `Copy`.

Also, it's worth noting that your `copy()` method doesn't technically copy, it returns a new instance. You may have intended this behaviour but this can be misleading for someone else that comes across your code.

A better name for your interface may be `Copyable`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was trying to do an mcve, hence I deleted the `copy()` method from the interface. Didn't know about covariant return types ! Sounds good :)